# "The system cannot find the drive specified" in .net 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio, process

I have two projects, one is in `.net 4.0` in `Visual Studio 2010` and the other `.net 4.7.2` in `Visual Studio 2017`.

When I use the same code:

```
Process.Start([path to a file on mapped drive])
```

It opens the file in the newer version but it complains in the old one:

> "The system cannot find the drive specified"

However, it works when I open the compiled version outside the `Visual Studio 2010`. And yes, I open `Visual Studio 2010` as `Administrator`.

Any remedy?

Comment: What's the context in which this code is running? I.e. is it inside a Winforms application, Console app, Services, Web app, etc? I suspect it's a web app and the next question (if it is) is how is it running in each instance? Under IIS express, full IIS, whatever the odd web server was that MS packaged at one point? Almost certainly it'll come down to the code in one instance running under a *different user account* that doesn't have the same drives mapped.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it's Windows Forms application.